# Application of Fubini's Theorem and Convolutions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and let $h = f * g$. Suppose that $\int y f(y) dy =0$ and $\int y g(y) dy =0$. Prove that $\int  y h(y) dy =0$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:} 
Let $$h(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)g(y) dy$$

We have, $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} y \left ( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y-t) g(t) dt \right) dy $$

Since $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, we have $$\int _{\mathbb{R}} f(y-t) g(t) dt $$

We will show,

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) dy  \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y)  dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y-t)g(t) dt dy$$

Since both integrable, we have $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y-t) g(t) dt dy= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y-t) g(t) dy dt$$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(t) \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y-t) dy dt$$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(t) \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) dy dt$$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(t) dt \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) dy$$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) dy \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) dy$$
Thus, $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} y \left ( \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) dy \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) dy \right)$$
$$ = \left ( \int_{\mathbb{R}} y \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) dy \right) \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) dy$$
$$ = \left ( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} y g(y) dy \right) \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) dy =0$$

I am a bit unsure about this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key lies in
$$ \int t g(t) \int f(y-t) \, dy \, dt = 0, $$
since $\int f(y-t) \, dy = \int f(y) \, dy $.
Then
$$ \int y h(y) \, dy = \int g(t) \left( \int y f(y-t) \, dy \right) \, dt \\
= \int g(t) \left( \int (y-t) f(y-t) \, dy \right) \, dt + \int t g(t) \left( \int f(y-t) \, dy \right) \, dt, $$
and then both of these are zero using the conditions in the question.